# Função recursiva Python printar de forma correta

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, recursão

Sou iniciando em python e gostaria que o resultado da minha execução fosse o seguinte:

```
[ [ 0 , 1 , 2 ] , [ 3 , 4 , 5 ] , [ 6 , 7 , 8 ] , [ 9 ] ]
[ ’ ∗ ∗ ∗ ∗ ’ , ’∗ ∗ ∗ ∗ ’ , ’ ∗ ∗ ’ ]
```

Mas não estou conseguindo.

Meu código está assim:

```
def g(a, b):
    if len(a) < b: return [a]
    return [a[:b]] + g(a,b + 1)


print(g(list(range(10)), 3))
print(g("*" * 10, 4))
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o tamanho das sub-listas é fixo, então o valor de `b` não deve mudar. Mas você estava somando 1 na chamada recursiva, o que aumenta o tamanho a ser considerado.

Na verdade o que deve mudar na chamada recursiva é a própria lista, então basta pegar do "b-ésimo" elemento em diante:

```
def g(a, b):
    if len(a) < b: return [a]
    return [a[:b]] + g(a[b:], b)
```

[Veja o código rodando no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/px73Kl).